# Flex android development. Network concerned

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, network-programming

I'm working on a flex android program now. In this application, I use AMF-channel to connect with my server. The app works well in wifi connection. However, when I disconnect from WIFI and try to run my app in GPRS, a strange box strike me.!
This is my first question on stack-overflow, so maybe I cannot use picture to describe the dialog. It's a dialog with strange border. My mobile screen cannot display the whole dialog. There's a text-input box (default input is "192.168.1.187")and two buttons(one named OK,the other cancel) following the text-input box. And at the bottom of the dialog there's another button called "Close".

When I run my app in no-wifi environment, the establishment process of channel is slow. And after several seconds, the dialog appears.

I don't know where the dialog is from. I'm sure I never define this ugly dialog in my code. And I've delete all the code in relation to the ip address "192.168.1.187"(It's my computer's ip address, I've tried to test my code in LAN)

After I log in my application, the dialog also appears per several seconds. But nothing happens in wifi connection.

```
static public function ConnectServer(url:String):void
    {
        channel = new AMFChannel("pyamf-channel",url);
        channel.connectTimeout = 15;


        channel.addEventListener(ChannelEvent.DISCONNECT,function(event:ChannelEvent):void{
            event.preventDefault();
            trace("Error1");
        });
        channel.addEventListener(ChannelFaultEvent.FAULT,function(event:ChannelFaultEvent):void{
            //event.preventDefault();
            trace("Error2");

        });
        channel.addEventListener(ChannelEvent.CONNECT,function(event:ChannelEvent):void{
            trace("connect success");
            if(channelSet != null)
            {
                remoteObject = new Remote_Object(channelSet,SystemParam.Remote_Service_Name);
                SystemParam.Remote_Service = remoteObject;

                trace("already go from here.");


            }
        });

        trace("spring comes."+ channel.toString());
        channelSet = new ChannelSet();
        channelSet.addChannel(channel);
        channel.connect(channelSet);

    }
```

I don't know what's wrong and how to do now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem had been solved last week.

I delete my project and check it out from server. Things get done.